# Excluding records from pandas DataFrame based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe, filter

I tried filtering my pandas DataFrame based on two conditions (`if`, `else`). Only the `if` statement works. The `if` statement keeps (flags) all records in my DataFrame based on 2 conditions (`logic1` and `logic2`). See section 4.

In the `else` statement, I would like to exclude all ids that have been flagged (`logic1` and `logic2`), without creating an extra list or looping over each record. Is there a way to filter out all these records without storing the ids in an extra list?

I would like to use the filter functions only, if possible. Currently I get the output from section 3. It is wrong because `id = 2` was flagged, but is still included in the output. The output I need is shown in section 4.

**Code**

```
logic1 = (potatoes['Desc'] == 'Bla2') & (potatoes['Value'] == True) & (potatoes['Enabled'] == True)
logic2 = (potatoes['Desc'].isin(['Bla8', 'Bla9'])) & (potatoes['Active'] == True) & (potatoes['Enabled'] == True)

if flagged:
    potatoes_flagged = potatoes[logic1 | logic2]
    return potatoes_flagged
else:
    potatoes_not_flagged = potatoes[~logic1 & ~logic2]
    return potatoes_not_flagged
```

**1. Input (potatoes)**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1  | Bla1 | 1      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla2 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] 
2  | Bla4 | 0      | 0       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla5 | 0      | 0       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3  | Bla6 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
4  | Bla7 | 0      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

**2. Output for flagged (if) (CORRECT)**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla2 | 1      | 1       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

**3. Output for not flagged (else) (WRONG)**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1  | Bla1 | 1      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla3 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla4 | 0      | 0       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2  | Bla5 | 0      | 0       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3  | Bla6 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
4  | Bla7 | 0      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

**4. Output needed for not flagged (CORRECT)**

```
id | Desc | Active | Enabled | Value | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1  | Bla1 | 1      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3  | Bla6 | 1      | 1       | 0     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
4  | Bla7 | 0      | 0       | 1     | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

Comment: I think you need `potatoes[~(logic1 & logic2)]`, but your expected output is wrong?

Comment: because, from your data, id=2 is never flagged here.

Comment: I don't see why `id=2` is never flagged and also `~logic1& ~logic2` seems to be correct.

Comment: I've updated 2 variable names. Maybe that confused you?

Comment: No, because if you print `logic1` and `logic2`, `logic2` is all False.

Comment: Jep but it is `logic1 | logic2`and since `logic1` is True?

Comment: I got what you wanted. It isn't as simple as a negation.

Comment: I don't understand why I received -2 :S

Comment: I did not downvote, but it took a herculean effort for me to understand what you really wanted. Users consider questions that are hard to understand/follow as ones that are not useful to the community and are hence downvoted.

Comment: Is there a way to find the reason?

Comment: No one can fathom why each individual downvotes... try to shrug it off.. I've had many of my questions (and answers) downvoted in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find all `id`s that are not returned by `potatoes[logic1 | logic2]`. You can use an inverted `isin` call to do so.

```
idx_flagged = potatoes.loc[logic1 | logic2, 'id'].values   
potatoes[~potatoes.id.isin(idx_flagged)]

   id  Desc  Active  Enabled  Value
0   1  Bla1       1        0      1
5   3  Bla6       1        1      0
6   4  Bla7       0        0      1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This answered my question.